# Unity3D RawImage(UI) Instantiate

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, instantiation

When I am instantiating prefab as GameObject there is no problem. But when instantiating prefab as RawImage there is NullReferenceException problem. (Prefab is RawImage if you need to know)

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Insstantia : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject img;

    public void Instan()
    {
        RawImage[] myObject = new RawImage[8];
        RectTransform[] rt = new RectTransform[8];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            myObject[i] = Instantiate(img, new Vector3(800 * i, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as RawImage;
            rt[i] = myObject[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            myObject[i].transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform, false);

            rt[i].anchorMin = new Vector2(0.05875f, 0);
            rt[i].anchorMax = new Vector2(0.94375f, 1);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are casting your GameObject prefab to a component type (RawImage) which is possible because the Component type inherits from the Object type.

So when you try to get a Component for example on this line:

```
rt[i] = myObject[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>();
```

A NullReferenceExceptiion is thrown because "img" gameObject has been cast to a Component type object and therefore the RectTransform Component does not exist.

Try changing your public GameObject img field to:

```
public RawImage img;
```

Comment: I doubt that will fix the Issue, instantiate creates a GameObject. RawImage is a component attached to the gameobject. The other way around will work though, when you change the myObject[] into a GameObject instead of a RawImage

Comment: Just tested it and it seems to work, that is of course, by changing the public field to public RawImage img and then casting to RawImage, which is what the OP was trying to do :)

Comment: He will need to change a few more casts then that as the RectTransform is not attached to the RawImage, but much rather to the instantiated object

Comment: Thanks for quick answers. I dont need Resources folder. My data is coming from web via json request and I am using Vuforia Cloud Reco. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to convert a `GameObject` into a `Component`. The instantiate command will create a GameObject for you, which in this case is your prefab with a component attached to it.

To fix this issue, you would just have to store the `GameObject` instead of the component, and if you were to need the RawImage component, obtain it in the same way as your RectTransform.

```
public GameObject[] myObject = new GameObject[8];
```

instead of

```
public RawImage[] myObject = new RawImage[8];
```

(and don't forget to change your conversion call from `as RawImage` To `as GameObject`)

If you are referring to a *Actual Image*, and not the component. You might want to take a look at [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) Instead of using Instantiate.